# Info dashboard users got Disappear ( php and my sql )

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

Hello everyone I have code for a registration and login system. When I log in I can see the user info like email and full name. I created a logout script with the unset session to logout. It's worked for me but when I logout and log in again the user's info got disappears. I am now having difficulty solving this problem. All of the code is below for refrence.
Logout script :

```html
<?php

  // Inialize session
  session_start();

// Delete certain session
  unset($_SESSION['userID']);
  // Delete all session variables
  // session_destroy();

 // Jump to login page
 header('Location: login.php');

  ?>
```

Login page :

```html
<?php

session_start();
// header.php
include ('header.php');
include "helper.php";
?>

<?php
    $user = array();
    require ('mysqli_connect.php');

    if(isset($_SESSION['userID'])){
        $user = get_user_info($con, $_SESSION['userID']);
    }

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
        require ('login-process.php');
    }
?>

<!-- registration area -->
<section id="login-form">
    <div class="row m-0">
        <div class="col-lg-4 offset-lg-2">
            <div class="text-center pb-5">
                <h1 class="login-title text-dark">Login</h1>
                <p class="p-1 m-0 font-ubuntu text-black-50">Login and enjoy additional features</p>
                <span class="font-ubuntu text-black-50">Create a new <a href="register.php">account</a></span>
            </div>
            <div class="upload-profile-image d-flex justify-content-center pb-5">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <img src="<?php echo isset($user['profileImage']) ? $user['profileImage'] : './assets/profile/beard.png' ; ?>" style="width: 200px; height: 200px" class="img rounded-circle" alt="profile">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                <form action="login.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="log-form">

                    <div class="form-row my-4">
                        <div class="col">
                            <input type="email" required name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email*">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-row my-4">
                        <div class="col">
                            <input type="password" required name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password*">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="submit-btn text-center my-5">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning rounded-pill text-dark px-5">Login</button>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<!-- #registration area -->


<?php
// footer.php
include ('footer.php');
?>
```

Helper script file:

```html
<?php

function validate_input_text($textValue){
    if (!empty($textValue)){
        $trim_text = trim($textValue);
        // remove illegal character
        $sanitize_str = filter_var($trim_text, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        return $sanitize_str;
    }
    return '';
}

function validate_input_email($emailValue){
    if (!empty($emailValue)){
        $trim_text = trim($emailValue);
        // remove illegal character
        $sanitize_str = filter_var($trim_text, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        return $sanitize_str;
    }
    return '';
}

// profile image
function upload_profile($path, $file){
    $targetDir = $path;
    $default = "beard.png";

    // get the filename
    $filename = basename($file['name']);
    $targetFilePath = $targetDir . $filename;
    $fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    If(!empty($filename)){
        // allow certain file format
        $allowType = array('jpg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'pdf');
        if(in_array($fileType, $allowType)){
            // upload file to the server
            if(move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $targetFilePath)){
                return $targetFilePath;
            }
        }
    }

    // return default image
    return $path . $default;
}


// get user info
function get_user_info($con, $userID){
    $query = "SELECT firstName, lastName, email, profileImage FROM user WHERE userID=?";
    $q = mysqli_stmt_init($con);

    mysqli_stmt_prepare($q, $query);

    // bind the statement
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($q, 'i', $userID);

    // execute sql statement
    mysqli_stmt_execute($q);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($q);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    return empty($row) ? false : $row;
}
```

Index profile user:

```html
<?php

session_start();
include ('header.php');
include ('helper.php');

$user = array();


if(isset($_SESSION['userID'])){
    require ('mysqli_connect.php');
    $user = get_user_info($con, $_SESSION['userID']);
}

?>

<section id="main-site">
    <div class="container py-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 offset-4 shadow py-4">
                <div class="upload-profile-image d-flex justify-content-center pb-5">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <img class="img rounded-circle" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;" src="<?php echo isset($user['profileImage']) ? $user['profileImage'] : './assets/profile/beard.png'; ?>" alt="">
                        <h4 class="py-3">
                            <?php
                            if(isset($user['firstName'])){
                                printf('%s %s', $user['firstName'], $user['lastName'] );
                            }
                            ?>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="user-info px-3">
                    <ul class="font-ubuntu navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-link"><b>First Name: </b><span><?php echo isset($user['firstName']) ? $user['firstName'] : ''; ?></span></li>
                        <li class="nav-link"><b>Last Name: </b><span><?php echo isset($user['lastName']) ? $user['lastName'] : ''; ?></span></li>
                        <li class="nav-link"><b>Email: </b><span><?php echo isset($user['email']) ? $user['email'] : ''; ?></span></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <center><a href='logout.php'><button name='logout' type='submit' class='btn btn-outline-primary'>Logout</button></a></center>
</section>

<?php
include "footer.php";
?>
```

My database table:

```html
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `user`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `userID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `profileImage` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `registerDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

my login-process code

```html
<?php

$error = array();

$email = validate_input_email($_POST['email']);
if (empty($email)){
    $error[] = "You forgot to enter your Email";
}

$password = validate_input_text($_POST['password']);
if (empty($password)){
    $error[] = "You forgot to enter your password";
}

if(empty($error)){
    // sql query
    $query = "SELECT userID, firstName, lastName, email, password, profileImage FROM user WHERE email=?";
    $q = mysqli_stmt_init($con);
    mysqli_stmt_prepare($q, $query);

    // bind parameter
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($q, 's', $email);
    //execute query
    mysqli_stmt_execute($q);

    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($q);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    if (!empty($row)){
        // verify password
        if(password_verify($password, $row['password'])){
            header("location: index.php");
            exit();
        }
    }else{
        print "You are not a member please register!";
    }

}else{
    echo "Please Fill out email and password to login!";
}
```

Thank you all.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What do you have in « login-process.php » ? I am asking because the first thing it will do when you try to login is call this file based on your code. So you may need to set more height in your login.php

Comment: i will add my login_process code thank you

Comment: Your user information are still DB, right?

Comment: no, i remove them

Comment: So if login works, you send directly the user to index.php, right?

Comment: yes exactly after that in index page the users info appear " email and full name " but when i logout and login again this infos despire i don't know why something in logout script session problem or somthing

Answer (score 0):

Info are gone because you never set them, you are getting `$result` in process-login.php, that you dont use. But you should.

To set all information in $_SESSION as followed: `$_SESSION["firstname"] = $result["firstName"]; $_SESSION["lastname"] = $result["lastName"];`

For example. Right before you set redirection to index.php.

What I put above is an example. But more or less, you need to set this infos.

```html
<?php

$error = array();

$email = validate_input_email($_POST['email']);
if (empty($email)){
    $error[] = "You forgot to enter your Email";
}

$password = validate_input_text($_POST['password']);
if (empty($password)){
    $error[] = "You forgot to enter your password";
}

if(empty($error)){
    // sql query
    $query = "SELECT userID, firstName, lastName, email, password, profileImage FROM user WHERE email=?";
    $q = mysqli_stmt_init($con);
    mysqli_stmt_prepare($q, $query);

    // bind parameter
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($q, 's', $email);
    //execute query
    mysqli_stmt_execute($q);

    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($q);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    if (!empty($row)){
        // verify password
        if(password_verify($password, $row['password'])){
            $_SESSION["firstname"] = $result["firstName"];  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            $_SESSION["lastname"] = $result["lastName"];    <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            
            header("location: index.php");
            exit();
        }
    }else{
        print "You are not a member please register!";
    }

}else{
    echo "Please Fill out email and password to login!";
}
```

Comment: and where are you now ?

Comment: in the index page i am trying to create result for the session to get the infos appear

Comment: @MawanTalal what does it show when you do `dump($result); die;` before your redirection in your login-process.php ? I edited my answer with partial example of what you should  (where I added <<<<). Is your project store somewhere ?